# Charles Web Proxy not showing Unity Web Requests

Tags: unity-game-engine, charles-proxy

I am working on an app that used `Unity.WWW` to make HTTP web requests. When we used this class, I could see all requests through Charles Web Proxy. We, just upgraded to use `UnityWebRequest` and now we can't see any of the calls that use this class in Charles, even though we can see them using WireShark.

Is there a way to configure Charles to capture these or is this a bug with Unity or possibly with Charles?

Comment: Me too!  I also would like to know what the deal is.

Comment: My team submitted this as a bug to Unity mid December, and they accepted it and are investigating.

Comment: same goes for the usage of BestHTTP in unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity fixed this bug in version 5.4.4p2:
https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases/5.4.4p2

Comment: also sometimes Charles can't see localhost requests so you might need to use `http://localhost.charlesproxy.com` instead of `http://localhost` in your client. Ref: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/localhost-traffic-doesnt-appear-in-charles/